# Apache POI SXSSF streaming output response

Tags: java, excel, csv, jersey, apache-poi

I have a Java Jersey service with an endpoint that generates a CSV file on request, and streams it back as StreamingOutput. Something like this:

```
return Response.ok((StreamingOutput) outputStream -> {
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // SOME TIME CONSUMING CALCULATIONS HERE
        writer.write("row" + i + ", foo " + i);
        writer.flush();
    }
    writer.close();
}).build();
```

Ignore any implementation or syntax errors, I'm just trying to convey the basic idea of how I'm splitting up the CSV file and writing it as a stream, row by row.

Now, my requirements have changed and I need to generate an Excel file with multiple sheets. So I've opted to use the Apache POI library.

I noticed it has `SXSSFWorkbook` class which is designated as a "streaming" version of a workbook. It seems like I still need to create the whole workbook before sending back the output though.

Is there a way to generate and stream back the workbook in pieces, as I'm currently doing with the CSV generation?

Comment: Excel files have lots of back-and-forward references, global references etc. SXSSF lets you stream bits into temporary files so you only need to keep global and reference bits in memory, but broadly you do need to have the while lot done before you can start sending stuff to a client

Comment: Do always look at `Excel` files as binary files. Either they are binary `BIFF` files (`*.xls`) or `Office Open XML`-ZIP archives (`*.xlsx`). Both cannot be handled by a `Writer`. Do writing them as files first. Then do streaming them like other binary files like images or PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess it's impossible to maintain the responsiveness of my current design while adding the "multi-sheet" Excel specific features then. Let's see what the stakeholders think is more important.